# having issues with posting json to the database - 301 moved permanently symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony, redirect

I am creating a webservice in symfony and I am trying to make a post call to the database. On making the post using postman I am getting the error 301 moved permanently.
this is my code for the controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/post/influ/")
 */
public function postAction(Request $request)
 {
   $data = new User;
   $firstname = $request->get('firstname');
   $lastname = $request->get('lastname');
   $username = $request->get('username');
   $gender = $request->get('gender');
   $email = $request->get('email');
   $country = $request->get('country');
   $state = $request->get('state');
   $password = $request->get('password');
   $retypePassword = $request->get('retypePassword');
 if(empty($firstname) || empty($lastname))
 {
   return new View("NULL VALUES ARE NOT ALLOWED", Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE); 
 } 
  $data->setFirstname($firstname);
  $data->setLastname($lastname);
  $data->setUsername($username);
  $data->setGender($gender);
  $data->setEmail($email);
  $data->setCountry($country);
  $data->setState($state);
  $data->setPassword($password);
  $data->setRetypePassword($retypePassword);
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($data);
  $em->flush();
   return (" Added Successfully", Response::HTTP_OK);
 }
```

this is the json I am posting to the database using postman but returning 301 moved permanently as a response

```
{
"id": 3,
"firstname": "xyz",
"lastname": "xyz",
"username": "hello",
"gender": "Male",
"email": "hello@yahoo.com",
"country": "MyContry",
"state": "MyState",
"password": "password",
"retype_password": "password"
}
```

this is the url I am making the post to

http://localhost:88/HelloApi/web/app_dev.php/post/influ

Please what could be wrong. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment, but if this action is somewhere in the file structure that requires login, the 301 could be moving your webservice over to a login page, which of course it doesn't know what to do with. Do you know where you're getting 301 redirected to?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can return a cleaner response :

```
<?php
return new Response(301);
```

I think the redirect problem does not come from your controller but more from your configuration of the **security.yml** file. Can you copy the **access control** part here please?